# Not able to prevent redirecting

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is script for action.

I want to prevent redirecting to url.

```
            $('#rem_btn').click(function(event) {
               event.preventDefault();

               var remove = $(this).attr('href');

               $.ajax({
                  type: 'get',
                  url: remove,
                  success: function(data) {
                    $('shop_pro_remove').html(data);
                  }
                });
              return false;
});
```

Comment: here is anchor <a id='rem_btn' href='remove_product.php?id=<?php echo $pro_id; ?>&name=<?php echo $product_name;?>'>
                         remove
                </a>

Comment: sorry! couldn't give it to time

Comment: Then take your time to read and ask a proper question when you're done. It's not nice to expect the community to spend time helping you when you're not willing to spend time yourself!

Comment: You have to find the time to take the [tour]. It teaches you much about how this website's system works. We can't help you much like this.

Comment: sorry please suggest me answer. i will read sure.

Comment: Please check my answer. If its not working add a comment.

Comment: Rino Raj now even click is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Please try this**

HTML:

```
<a id='rem_btn' rel='remove_product.php?id=<?php echo $pro_id; ?>&name=<?php echo $product_name;?>' href="javascript:void(0)"> remove </a>
```

AJAX call:

```
$('#rem_btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var remove = $(this).attr('rel');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: remove,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#shop_pro_remove').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

The reason you’d want to do this with the `href` of a link is that normally, a `javascript:` URL will redirect the browser to a plain text version of the result of evaluating that JavaScript. But if the result is `undefined`, then the browser stays on the same page. `void(0)` is just the smallest script possible that evaluates as `undefined`.

[Reference VOID](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/void)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you're missing a closing } and a ). Second, there is an invalid selector in your ajax success callback , you probably wanted to use a class or an id.

Should look like:

```
$('#rem_btn').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var remove = $(this).attr('href');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: remove,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#shop_pro_remove').html(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? The preventDefault? The ajax call? The success callback of the ajax call? You'll need to be a bit more specific. Furthermore, are you seeing any logs in the console?

Comment: Yeah ajax call is not working i remove script or keep it ,resulting same . result is just showed on url page

Comment: here is  my anchor <a id='rem_btn' href='remove_product.php?id=<?php echo $pro_id; ?>&name=<?php echo $product_name;?>'> remove </a>

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand a word you're saying

Comment: first i m using ajax here just to perform action of unset id to remove product  not performing any action on database

Comment: <?php session_start(); ?>
<?php  require('includes/connection.php');  //include connection file ?>
<?php

// get the product id
$id =$_GET['id'];

$name =$_GET['name'];
 
// remove the item from the array
unset($_SESSION['cart_array'][$id]);

// redirect to product list and tell the user it was added to cart
echo" $name was removed from your cart!";
?>